# Text over figure in the wrapfigure environment

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

I know this question has been asked before, but I could not find a suitable answer, so please bear with me.

I want to put a figure in my document using the `wrapfigure` environment. It is supposed to be on the left side of the document with width = `0.25\textwidth`. I have used a `flushleft` environment within the `wrapfigure` environment to keep everything formatted properly. This works fine in some parts of the document, but in others the figure ends up in the middle of the page, with body text over it.

I have noticed that this happens near long blocks of text. If I have a figure that is supposed to be to the left of a long block of body text, then it messes up. However, if I break the text up into smaller paragraphs and put the `wrapfigure` environment between them, it works. The problem is that I don't want my paragraphs to be broken in strange places to accommodate my figures. There must be a better way of formatting this. Thanks in advance for your help!

Note: I don't think there are no page breaks in the problem area. I saw that this was a problem for one person, so I thought I should point that out ahead of time. Besides body text, there are only breaks for `sections` and displayed equations. Of course, I'm no expert at typesetting so I could be wrong.

[Edit]: Here is my MWE. I realize it isn't exactly minimal, but it's the best I could do without making the problem disappear.

```
\documentclass[]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\ex}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ey}{0}

\newcommand{\figureone}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
    \draw [fill = lightgray] (0,0) circle [radius = 1.25 cm];
    \draw (0,0) -- (0.8838834765,0.8838834765);
    \node [above left] at (0.5,0.5) {$r$};
    \node [above left] at (-1.0,0.575) {$C$};
    \draw [->] (\ex,\ey) ++(135:1.5cm) arc (135:85:1.5cm);
    \draw [->] (\ex,\ey) ++(160:1.5cm) arc (160:210:1.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\figuretwo}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
    \draw [fill = lightgray] rectangle (2,2);
    \node [right, rotate=90] at (2.35,0.4) {1 unit};
    \node [below] at (1,-0.1) {1 unit};
    \node [above] at (1,1) {$A = 1$};
    \node [below] at (1,1) {$\textrm{unit}^2$};
    \draw [<-] (0,-0.375) -- (0.35,-0.375);
    \draw [->] (1.65,-0.375) -- (2,-0.375);
    \draw (0,-0.15) -- (0,-0.6);
    \draw (2,-0.15) -- (2,-0.6);
    \draw [<-](2.375,0) -- (2.375,0.35);
    \draw [->](2.375,1.65) -- (2.375,2);
    \draw (2.15,0) -- (2.6,0);
    \draw (2.15,2) -- (2.6,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
    \figureone{}
\end{flushleft}
\caption{Caption}
\end{wrapfigure}

\noindent
Filler text: here is some filler text. In my document this is 7 lines long, including one displayed equation. The first figure should be positioned directly to the right of this text.

\section*{Section 1}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
    \figuretwo{}
\end{flushleft}
\caption{Caption}
\end{wrapfigure} 

\lipsum[1]

\section*{Section 2}

\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate your problem.  Could you please provide a MWE which illustrates the issue?

Comment: @A.Ellett I tried to duplicate the problem myself on a new document, but couldn't. The only way I could do it was by modifying the actual code I used. I made this working example as short as possible, but it's hardly "minimal." When you compile this code (exactly as written), I believe it will illustrate the problem.

Comment: @fctaylor25 your example code shows that you are using `wrapfigure` in the wrong way: specifically, there's not enough text to wrap around the first `wrapfigure`. Perhaps this is what you meant? `\section*{Section 1}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
    \figureone{}
\end{flushleft}
\caption{Caption}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\section*{Section 2}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft}
    \figuretwo{}
\end{flushleft}
\caption{Caption}
\end{wrapfigure} 
\lipsum[2-3]
`

Comment: In fact, no need for `flushleft`: `\section*{Section 1}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
    \figureone{}
\caption{Caption}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\section*{Section 2}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
    \figuretwo{}
\caption{Caption}
\end{wrapfigure} 
\lipsum[2-3]`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but removing `flushleft` doesn't change anything. Your code works, but you left out the filler text before section 1. When I put that in, the error comes back.

Comment: @fctaylor25 yes, removing `flushleft` (which is not needed), changes the vertical positioning of the figure. This works OK for me: `\noindent
Filler text.
\section*{Section 1}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
    \figureone{}
\caption{Caption}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1]

\section*{Section 2}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
    \figuretwo{}
\caption{Caption}
\end{wrapfigure} 
\lipsum[2-3]`

Comment: I see what's going on. Your code works, but you've moved the first figure into the first section. It doesn't belong there: I would like it to go next to a paragraph of text that precedes this section. I only wrote "Filler text" instead of the entire paragraph to make the example code as short as possible. Basically, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve putting the first `wrapfigure` in the first section. Thanks for your help, I hope this makes sense. I'm changing my MWE to reflect the fact that there is more text in the beginning.

Comment: @fctaylor25 As long as the text is enough to wrap, there should be no mayor problems; although it's better not to have too many `wrapfigure` environments too close.

Comment: Is there another way to have figures on one side and text on the other?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have enough text in order to surround your images with it. When I add some dummy-text here, it works just fine.

If you do not have enough text, you can use a `multicolumn` environment or you put it in a `tabbing` or a simple `tabular`. This will make it less flexible but fully controllable.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{lipsum}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ex}{0}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ey}{0}    
    \newcommand{\figureone}[1]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
        \draw [fill = lightgray] (0,0) circle [radius = 1.25 cm];
        \draw (0,0) -- (0.8838834765,0.8838834765);
        \node [above left] at (0.5,0.5) {$r$};
        \node [above left] at (-1.0,0.575) {$C$};
        \draw [->] (\ex,\ey) ++(135:1.5cm) arc (135:85:1.5cm);
        \draw [->] (\ex,\ey) ++(160:1.5cm) arc (160:210:1.5cm);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \newcommand{\figuretwo}[1]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
        \draw [fill = lightgray] rectangle (2,2);
        \node [right, rotate=90] at (2.35,0.4) {1 unit};
        \node [below] at (1,-0.1) {1 unit};
        \node [above] at (1,1) {$A = 1$};
        \node [below] at (1,1) {$\textrm{unit}^2$};
        \draw [<-] (0,-0.375) -- (0.35,-0.375);
        \draw [->] (1.65,-0.375) -- (2,-0.375);
        \draw (0,-0.15) -- (0,-0.6);
        \draw (2,-0.15) -- (2,-0.6);
        \draw [<-](2.375,0) -- (2.375,0.35);
        \draw [->](2.375,1.65) -- (2.375,2);
        \draw (2.15,0) -- (2.6,0);
        \draw (2.15,2) -- (2.6,2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}    
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
            \figureone{}
        \caption{Caption}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    \noindent
    Filler text: here is some filler text. In my document this is 7 lines long, including one displayed equation. The first figure should be positioned directly to the right of this text.

    \section*{Section 1}
        \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.25\textwidth}
            \figuretwo{}
            \caption{Caption}
        \end{wrapfigure}        
    \lipsum[1-3]    
    \section*{Section 2}    
    \lipsum[2-3]    
\end{document}
```

[image]